# mongoosastic index data not getting deleted after removing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

Currently i am using mongoose Model.remove method to remove a document. But after removing document mongoosastic index still contains deleted document index.

```
User.remove({_id:userId}, function(err) {    
   if (err) {       
      res.json({success:false});    
   }
   else {
      res.json({success:true}) 
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because mongoose calls the delete index hook only when you do a `user.remove()` instead of `User.remove({_id: userId})`, for that reason mongoosastic could not delete this document.

You can see that in mongoostatic docs about removing documents:

https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#removing-a-document